# Why does the symbolic link /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 keeps getting automatically reset?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, symbolic-link

I built a docker container using the nvidia docker image `nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04` on my ubuntu server to run pytorch programs. The server is installed with nvidia driver version 430.26, while the docker image comes with a driver of version 440.118.02. In directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` inside the docker container, there are the following files whose names contain `libcuda`:

```
root@cuda102cudnn8_3ddepth:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ls -la libcuda*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       12 Nov 27 08:45 libcuda.so -> libcuda.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       21 Nov 27 12:33 libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.440.118.02
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16120456 Jun  4  2019 libcuda.so.430.26
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16824128 Sep  3 10:08 libcuda.so.440.118.02
```

Now, for GPU-based pytorch programs to run on GPU, the nvidia driver version that the docker container uses should not exceed that installed on the host machine. So I have to manually relink `libcuda.so.1` to `libcuda.430.26` (and this does work).

What is weird is that the link keeps getting reset to `libcuda.so.440.118.02` after a while. I am not sure what triggers this. But I can be sure that restarting the container will reset the link while `source ~/.bashrc` won't. I think it also gets reset after I have installed something, but I can't be sure.

What could possibly trigger this automatic reset? I really don't want to reset the link manually every time. If I try to rename or remove `libcuda.so.440.118.02` I get

```
root@cuda102cudnn8_3ddepth:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# rm -rf libcuda.so.440.118.02
rm: cannot remove 'libcuda.so.440.118.02': Device or resource busy
```

What can I do?

Comment: This is in a container? Do you restart the container? Why not just build an image based on that one with the change made?

Comment: @muru Yes. all this happens inside the container. Since it is running on a remote server, I don't really need to restart it frequently. The thing is, I noticed that something other than restarting the container can also trigger the resetting of the link, but I am not sure what. As for building a new image, I am not sure it'll work unless I figure out what triggered the reset.